# Split string and replace Discord emoji to [name]

Tags: python, string, discord

I have incoming messages such as `<a:GG:123456789> <:1Copy:12345678><:14:1256678>:eyes:Hello friend!:eyes:` and I want this output to be `[GG] [1Copy][14][eyes]Hello friend![eyes]`

The below code is what I currently have and it works *kind of*. The above incoming example outputs `[GG] [1Copy] [14] [eyes]`

```
def shorten_emojis(content):
    seperators = ("<a:", "<:")

    output = []

    for chunk in content.split():
        if any(match in chunk for match in seperators):
            parsed_chunk = []

            new_chunk = chunk.replace("<", ";<").replace(">", ">;")

            for emo in new_chunk.split(";"):
                if emo.startswith(seperators):
                    emo = f"<{splits[1]}>" if len(splits := emo.split(":")) == 3 else emo

                parsed_chunk.append(emo)

            chunk = "".join(parsed_chunk)

        output.append(chunk)

    output = " ".join(output)

    for e in re.findall(":.+?:", content):
        output = output.replace(e, f"<{e.replace(':', '')}>")

    return output
```

### Test #1

Input: `<a:GG:123456789> <:1Copy:12345678><:14:1256678>:eyes:Hello friend!:eyes:`

Output: `[GG] [1Copy] [14] :eyes:Hello friend!:eyes:`

Desired `[GG] [1Copy][14][eyes]Hello friend![eyes]`

### Test #2

Input: `<a:cryLaptop:738450655395446814><:1Copy:817543814481707030><:14:817543815401439232> <:thoonk:621279654711656448><:coolbutdepressed:621279653675532290><:KL1Heart:585547199480332318>Nice<:dogwonder:621251869058269185> OK:eyes:`

Output: `[cryLaptop] [1Copy] [14] [thoonk] [coolbutdepressed] [KL1Heart] Nice [dogwonder] OK:eyes:`

Desired `[cryLaptop] [GG] [1Copy] [14] [thoonk] [coolbutdepressed] [KL1Heart] Nice [dogwonder] OK[eyes]`

### Edit

I have edited my code block, it now works as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a single pattern with an alternation `|` to match both variations. Then in the callback of sub, you can check for the existence of group 1.

```
<a?:([^:<>]+)[^<>]*>|:([^:]+):
```

The pattern matches

- `<a?:` Match `<`, optional `a` and `:`
- `([^:<>]+)` Capture in **group 1** any char except `:` `<` and `>`
- `[^<>]*>` Optionally match any char except `<` and `>`, then match `>`
- `|` Or
- `:([^:]+):` Capture in **group 2** all between `:`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7bqxYX/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/d3i6CE).

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"<a?:([^:<>]+)[^<>]*>|:([^:]+):"
def shorten_emojis(content):
    return re.sub(
        pattern, lambda x: f"[{x.group(1)}]" if x.group(1) else f"[{x.group(2)}]"
        ,content
    )

print(shorten_emojis("<a:GG:123456789> <:1Copy:12345678><:14:1256678>:eyes:Hello friend!:eyes:"))
print(shorten_emojis("<a:cryLaptop:738450655395446814><:1Copy:817543814481707030><:14:817543815401439232> <:thoonk:621279654711656448><:coolbutdepressed:621279653675532290><:KL1Heart:585547199480332318>Nice<:dogwonder:621251869058269185> OK:eyes:"))
```

Output

```
[GG] [1Copy][14][eyes]Hello friend![eyes]
[cryLaptop][1Copy][14] [thoonk][coolbutdepressed][KL1Heart]Nice[dogwonder] OK[eyes]
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution and is much shorter and more consistent than mine. Thanks for the explanation too!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regular expressions. It is a library that already includes Python itself.

I have modified the code a bit to make it more compact but I think it is understood the same.

The most important thing is to detect the three groups of words. With `(<. *?>)` We select the `<words>`, with `(:. *? :)` the `: word:` and with `(. *?)` The rest of the text.

Then we must format it with the expected values and display them.

```
import re
def shorten_emojis(content):
    tags = re.findall('((<.*?>)|(:.*?:)||(.*?))', content)
    output=""
    for tag in tags:
        if re.findall("<.*?>", tag[0]):
            valor=re.search(':.*?:', tag[0])
            output+=f"[{valor.group()[1:-1]}]"
        elif re.match(":.*?:", tag[0]):
            output+=f"[{tag[0][1:-1]}]"
        else:
            output+=f"{tag[0]}"

    return output


print(shorten_emojis("<a:GG:123456789> <:1Copy:12345678><:14:1256678>:eyes:Hello friend!:eyes:"))
print(shorten_emojis("<a:cryLaptop:738450655395446814><:1Copy:817543814481707030><:14:817543815401439232> <:thoonk:621279654711656448><:coolbutdepressed:621279653675532290><:KL1Heart:585547199480332318>Nice<:dogwonder:621251869058269185> OK:eyes:"))
```

RESULT:

```
[GG] [1Copy][14][eyes]Hello friend![eyes]
[cryLaptop][1Copy][14] [thoonk][coolbutdepressed][KL1Heart]Nice[dogwonder] OK[eyes]
```